# Microsoft Search Server 2010 Accessing different content sources in C#

Tags: c#, search-server-2010

I have created two different content sources in my Microsoft Search Server 2010 and I am wondering how I can access the crawl results for them individually in C#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setup scopes for each content source and when you make your query include the name of the scope.  A useful tool that helped in our development was [Mossman's FAST for SharePoint tool](http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/)